# Unable to set number of output channels for Audio Render

Tags: rendering, audio

I can't seem to find where to set the number of output channels for an Audio Render. I can control the output format for live playback in preferences but this seems to have no effect on audio rendering. The documentation suggests there should be a button or setting in the scene's output panel but on my version it doesn't seem to be there.

Am I looking in the wrong place? Also peeked through the parameters for the `sound.mixdown` operator and it doesn't seem to be settable there, nor is it available on `bpy.context.scene`.

I'm running 2.90.0 on Mac OS X Catalina.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The audio options are visible once you choose ffmepg video as File format.

Then you can set the audio codec and channels in the audio section of the encoding.

[image]